# The positive Laplacian is indeed the negative Laplacian

Tags: calculus, analysis, education, laplacian

I know this question sounds like a joke. And it probably is:).

I found it kind of annoying, but also interesting, to call $-\Delta=-\sum_{j=1}^n\partial^2_{jj}$ "the positive Laplacian" as it is the positive operator with respect to standard $L^2$-pairing. But in the mean time it is also regarded as the "negative of Laplacian" since we have a minus sign.

I think there are two different questions related to this topic.

1. What is a more clear way to explain the difference on what positive and negative is for a Laplacian? And also how to use such terminologies appropriately in different circumstances.

I believe such clarification is important, as the Hodge-Laplacian $\Box=dd^*+d^*d$ (let me not using $\Delta$ here) can be called a "positive Laplacian" with slightly less ambiguity. Also the word "subharmonic functions" refers to those $f$ such that $-\Delta f\le0$, but not $\Delta f\le0$.

2. Are other similar (but also interesting) confusions happen in other fields of mathematics? If I remember correctly, the meaning of covariant tensors and contravariant tensors in commutative algebra and in differential geometry are flip. They seem less "annoying" than Laplacian though.

Comment: @fGDu94 No. Technically speaking both Laplacians are elliptic. In one defintion elliptic operators are whose principle symbols have no zero outside the origin.

Comment: Also, possibly adding to the sign confusion, the graph laplacian is the positive definite one.

Comment: @NickAlger Thanks for the suggestion. But I am not familar with that. Does the graph Laplacian becomes $-\Delta$, say, if we take the inductive limit $m\to\infty$ on $2^{-m}\mathbb Z^n$?

Comment: Up to some scalings and under some conditions it can be thought of as a discretization of the negative continuous Laplacian. The Laplacian somehow measures how much a function deviates from it's local average, and the graph Laplacian extends that idea to functions defined on discrete graphs.

Answer (score 3):

We call $-\Delta$ the positive Laplacian since it is positive semi-definite as a self-adjoint operator on, say, $C_c^\infty({\mathbb R}^n)$, the space of functions with compact support under the $L^2$ inner product. That is, if $f, g\in C_c^\infty({\mathbb R}^n)$, then
\begin{align*}
\langle -\Delta f, g\rangle &= \int_{{\mathbb R}^n} (-\Delta f) g = \int_{{\mathbb R}^n} f(-\Delta g) = \langle f, -\Delta g\rangle,\\
\langle -\Delta f, f\rangle &= \int_{{\mathbb R}^n} (-\Delta f) f = \int_{{\mathbb R}^n} |\nabla f|^2 \geq 0,
\end{align*}
where the identities hold by integration by parts and there are no boundary terms by the compact support condition. Then the eigenvalues of $-\Delta$ are nonnegative.

The Hodge-Laplacian $\square = dd^* + d^*d$ is, by construction, self-adjoint and positive semi-definite. Actually on a function $f$ on a compact manifold,
$$
\square f = - \Delta f. 
$$

A $C^2$ function is subharmonic iff $\Delta f\geq 0$, and the reason is that such function lies below a harmonic function with the same boundary condition.

Comment: Thanks! Let me see if there are more comprehensive discussion on this, since this is also what I taught to students.